# how do i get the heap dump of a java application running in flexible environment

Tags: app-engine-flexible

Given a java application running in flexible environment, how is it possible to get a heap dump to see the heavy objects? 
I would ideally import this into a tool like eclipse mat and analyze the heap dump. 
Another great option would be for stackdriver profiler showing it but i just see there cpu profiling but not memory profiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to a Flex instance with ssh in a similar fashion that you connect to GCE VM instances. Read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance).  Once connected you can get the heap dump like you usually do.

Comment: i have now just a problem that making jmap with live option kills my server but this is a different problem.

Comment: We have connected to the instance but it seems that you can only run jmap/jcmd from the user that started the JVM. Do you know of a way around this?

rror attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: cannot open binary file
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: cannot open binary file