# Where to find the heap dump in App Engine (Flex)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, heap-dump

Our Google Appengine flex app has configured HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.. we did have a few crashes due to OOM. But where can we find the heap dump?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, in App Engine, there isn't a way to track heap dump logs directly using Stackdriver - the tool used for logging in App Engine. The developers at Google are aweare of it and you can track the Feature Request for this functionality [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/116973619).

In alternative to that, you can try one thing. As indicated in this other similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874290/how-do-i-get-the-heap-dump-of-a-java-application-running-in-flexible-environment), you can enable the debug mode in your instance and then, connect to it via SSH. Once you connect via SSH, you need to run the following commands.

1. `sudo docker ps` - to list the containers of your instance and find the one related to your project ID;
2. `sudo docker logs [CONTAINER-NAME]` - with the name got from the last command, get the logs here;
3. Or start a shell to check it further with `sudo docker exec -it [CONTAINER-NAME] /bin/bash`

All these steps are further explained and with more information in the official documentation: [Debugging an instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance)

Let me know if the information helped you!